# R - Set environment variable permanently

Tags: r, environment-variables

I'd like to set the default distribution of Python for my Reticulate package to use. I use,

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

however, I have to re-enter this line of code every time I start R. How can I set this permanently, so I don't need to specify which Python distribution I need every time?

Comment: Add that line to your RProfile

Comment: I did and it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have other Rprofile content? Is it loading upon startup? `.Rprofile` should be located here: `Sys.getenv("R_USER")`

Comment: Sys.getenv("R_USER") returns "" (blank)

Comment: I'd try creating a file called `.Rprofile` and putting it in your working directory. Add this line: `.First <- function() cat("\014\ntesting\ntesting")` to the file. If your R profile is loading it will print "testing testing" to the console upon startup. If this doesn't work Google is your friend.

Comment: @BrianDavis: Do you mean `R_HOME`? I think `R_USER` is Windows specific.

Answer (score 20):

On Windows, use `Sys.getenv('R_USER')` as @Brian Davis suggested in the comments to know the location of your home folder. On Linux, `Sys.getenv('HOME')` should be your normal home folder which you should use.

Now open up a terminal (if you're using recent versions of Rstudio there is one next to the console), go to your home folder and add a `.Renviron` file. You can do this without using the terminal too, but you'll probably have to confirm creation of a file starting with a dot.

```
cd path_to_my_home_Folder
touch .Renviron
```

Add `RETICULATE_PYTHON = /usr/local/bin/python3` to it, and add also a new line at the end. Your file should look like this (if it's new):

```
> RETICULATE_PYTHON = /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Now you should be able to access your environment variable with `Sys.getenv('RETICULATE_PYTHON')` at each R session, since R looks for any `.Renviron` file defining environment variables in R home folder at startup (see documentation for startup`?Startup`).

**UPDATE 29/10/2018**

As it turnouts the variables defined with `.Renviron` are available only within Rstudio, which is not so much of a surprise since the `.Renviron` file is read at Rstudio startup. If you want the environment variable to be available for `Rscript` (for instance), you can :

**Windows** Add it to your user environment variables, using the `Modify environment variables` utility (available in the Start menu search bar)

**Mac** You can do the exact same procedure as above but do that on your `.bash_profile` instead of `.Rstudio`. Open up a terminal and place yourself to your user root folder (default location of the terminal usually). Add the following line (without blanks around the equal sign):

```
export RETICULATE_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Save and close, restart terminal. The terminal reads your `.bash_profile` at start up, thus defining the environment variables. Your `RETICULATE_PYTHON` should now be available even in non-interactive R sessions.

Comment: I think the update part from 2018 is not true (anymore?). Also plain R or Rscript read the `.Renviron` file, unless you manually forbid it with the `--no-environ` parameter.

Answer (score 14):

The packge `usethis` has a function that opens the file `.Renviron` of your home folder.

```
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```

Once the file is opened, you just need add your pair key=value, save and close it.

```
RETICULATE_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
```