# How to send R variable to bash and again being read by another R process?

Tags: r, bash

I am trying to create a process mainly using `R`, where a R variable will be sent to `bash` and then another `Rscript file` will read that value from `bash`, do some calculation based on that.

My primary `R code` looks like below -

```
library(parallel) 
mclapply(letters, 
                    function(Let) 
                        return(system("/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript '/opt/R/Try.R' $Let")), mc.cores = 6)
```

So, basically in above code, the individual letters are being sent to bash through variable `Let`, and then the 2nd R process `'Try.R'` will read that value and print it.

My `'Try.R'` looks like below -

```
GetValue = commandArgs(TRUE)

print(GetValue); flush.console()

quit(save = "no")
```

With above implementation, it doesnt look like the value of `'Let'` variable is getting passed to `bash`. Can someone please help me with right approach. The codes above I put just for explanation purpose to describe what I am trying to do, and hence can be executed directly in `R` without passing to `bash`, however my actual process is quite complex so needs this kind of implementation.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

I am using *Ubuntu 18 machine with latest R*.

Comment: How are you declaring `Let`? R env won't survive a session, e.g. via `R` then `Sys.setenv(Let = 4); q('no')`. Check `env | grep Let` and you'll see `Let` hasn't survived

Comment: You might benefit from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49738564/3576984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to execute the bash file (and not read in the output), then the below will work:

First I write the R script:

```
BASH = c("GetValue = commandArgs(TRUE)",
"print(GetValue); flush.console()","quit(save='no')")

writeLines(BASH,"./Try.R")
```

And I execute the `system` call like you did, except to have the command line as a character that includes the variable, and run that:

```
library(parallel) 
mclapply(letters,function(Let){
CMD = paste("Rscript ./Try.R",Let)
return(system(CMD))}, 
mc.cores = 6)
```